# ReactJS - Script DOM node

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

I'm trying to see how can i use `ReactDOM.script` node with an external script (eg: `src=http://.....js`).

It seems that everyone already noticed that it does not work. I couldn't find a solution to that problem (I really want to avoid Iframes).

Doesn't anyone has a solution for that ?

Thanks :)

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to Ben and Felix. The solution (for Stripe, read comments below) is to use the script in the body of the "index.html" with the custom checkout form.

Comment: *"that this doesn't work"* What about it does not work? Either way it seems rather odd to render a `script` element in React, since it's a UI element. What's the use case?

Comment: Payment gatway from Stripe :(
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Thanks for the english correction :)

Comment: Oh I see. So it actually does render something into the DOM. What is the problem you are facing though? "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description and it doesn't help others to identify whether they have the same problem. (p.s.: using "doesn't" is perfectly fine ;) )

Comment: You probably want to do a custom Stripe checkout integration which gives you more control over exactly how the checkout button is initialized: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: Ok sorry for not being clear enough :). Using `ReactDOM.script {...some attributs...}` doesn't work at all with ReactJS. I think this is linked to some security issues. ReactJS add the `script` node to the DOM but the JS-script is not downloaded and not executed :/

I would like to make it executed. Instead I'm using an IFrame but I don't like this solution because some UI effects are restrained to that IFrame :(

Ok Ben, I didn't thought about using the custom solution. I'll give it a go. ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it, but there is a library called ReactScriptLoader that loads components that require third party scripts. [Here](https://github.com/yariv/ReactScriptLoader#a-stripe-checkout-example) is an example for Stripe.

Answer (score -1):

something that may help you in the future is to install the react chrome developer extension.  It displays the DOM in nodes of react components.

Here is the link :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi